# JBoss Fuse: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource has no uri for installed bundle

Tags: osgi, jbossfuse, fuseesb, blueprint-osgi

I'm working on JBossFuse 6.2, have a CXF endpoint for which I needed to set up some special properties through `httpj:engine-factory` configuration block. Upon trying that I hit this issue:
[MapMetadataImpl not found by org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-3499)

The error was the following:

```
> ERROR | pool-43-thread-1 | BlueprintContainerImpl | 14 -
> org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.2 | Unable to start blueprint
> container for bundle test-ws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/aries/blueprint/reflect/MapMetadataImpl at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.blueprint.JettyServerEngineFactoryParser.parseEngineConnector(JettyServerEngineFactoryParser.java:110)
> at
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.blueprint.JettyServerEngineFactoryParser.parse(JettyServerEngineFactoryParser.java:83)
```

It appeared when trying to add the httpj block for CXF definition.

```
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <httpj:engine port="${port}" host="${host}">
        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="${minThreads}" maxThreads="${maxThreads}"/>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

I tried the solution provided in the referred posts that is installing the osgi bundle for Blueprint Core Compatibility.

```
osgi:install mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility/1.0.0
```

However, after installing the bundle upon container start I get the following exception:

```
 2016-06-22 11:01:13,279 | ERROR | 63859-1-thread-1 | DeploymentAgent                  | ?? | 83 - io.fabric8.fabric-agent - 1.2.0.redhat-133 | Unable to update agent 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource has no uri
    at io.fabric8.agent.service.Deployer.getBundleInputStream(Deployer.java:1354)[83:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.2.0.redhat-133]
    at io.fabric8.agent.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:714)[83:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.2.0.redhat-133]
    at io.fabric8.agent.service.Agent.provision(Agent.java:348)[83:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.2.0.redhat-133]
    at io.fabric8.agent.service.Agent.provision(Agent.java:194)[83:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.2.0.redhat-133]
    at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:642)[83:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.2.0.redhat-133]
    at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$2.run(DeploymentAgent.java:256)[83:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.2.0.redhat-133]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
```

Has anybody ever applied the proposed solution in JbossFuse? I don't even understand that much why that exception is being fired.

Comment: Could you try with JBoss Fuse **6.2.1** instead? Bundle `org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility` is provided and you just need to start it. Locate its ID with `list -t 0 | grep ries` and then start it.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna Thanks for your reply but 6.2.1 is not an option at this moment as we are approaching the go live date. I know it should make no difference, but given it has several bug fixes and enhancements over 6.2, might be a bit risky. 

I have contacted a guy in RH and provided a solution, as soon as I can try it, if it works, I'll post it online for so any other facing this issue has the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I anybody falls into this, I got an answer from someone at Red Hat. The problem I was having is that I was on a Fabric environment, so I had to add the OSGi Blueprint Core Compatibility bundle to the Karaf profile in the Fabric. It can be done from the karaf console by running the following command

```
profile-edit --bundles mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility/1.0.0 karaf 1.x
```

Where 1.x is current fabric version in use.

If you are NOT on a fabric environment, then the solution posted above should work just as is.

Hope this helps!